# Automatic(ish) cgroups with systemD

Tags: systemd, opensuse, cgroups

I am building an appliance via SuseStudio, I need some advice about cgroups.
I am trying to make the cgroups/cexec automatic, sort of like a user-land container, that runs before the user can login.  This is actually an experiment, and I need some help on how to make this work correctly.

Scenario:
1 computer with a 4 core CPU and 16GB ram, split CPU into sockets 0 and 1, each containing 2 cores.  Socket 1 needs to be limited to non-user applications, and system stuffs.  Socket 0 is user-land, any and all user programs, DEs, and such must be jailed here.  I have noticed that on average most Linux distro's do not need much ram to run a terminal w/o X, so I would assign <= 4GB ram to socket 1.  I have read a lot of documentation that leads me to believe this is possible, but every solution shows that application to be run on a certain sockets must be executed like this: `cexec %commandhere%`.  While this may be the standard way, it won't work in this scenario, since my children will be using this machine, and that's a lot for a 5 year old to remember.

So my question is can someone give me a simple example to make cgroups function this way and possible give me some tips on how to make it automatic(no need for "cexec")?